# js RegEx: Remove callback function call, but keep the argument (the JSON)

Tags: json, regex, api, callback

I'm using a thesaurus API to get synonyms from a word.

Here is the link:

http://thesaurus.altervista.org/testjs

It is returning a string which is supposed to contain JSON data, but it's wrapped in a callback function which I suspect is causing JSON.parse() to choke and I don't know how to remove/bypass it:

```
//results from 'elephant'
process({"response":[{"list":{"category":"(noun)","synonyms":"proboscidean|proboscidian"}},{"list":{"category":"(noun)","synonyms":"emblem|allegory"}}]})
```

I have tried it without the callback but it doesn't work and I found the reason for that: ["HTTP response with "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", but only if the HTTP request is performed using the optional parameter "callback""](http://thesaurus.altervista.org/forum/index.php?forum=3&thread=1355490905).

So my theory is, maybe regular expressions can strip the `process()` off of it, then hopefully JSON.parse will be happy. Thanks.

Comment: So, did you try `var js = JSON.parse(s.replace(/^process\(|\)$/g, ''));`?

Comment: Yes, I got an Object :) Thanks stribizhev!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to obtain a string that will be parseable by `JSON.parse`, remove the initial `process(` and final `)`:

```
var js = JSON.parse(s.replace(/^process\(|\)$/g, ''));
```

See the snippet:

```js
var s = 'process({"response":[{"list":{"category":"(noun)","synonyms":"proboscidean|proboscidian"}},{"list":{"category":"(noun)","synonyms":"emblem|allegory"}}]})';
var js = JSON.parse(s.replace(/^process\(|\)$/g, ''));
document.getElementById("r").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(js);
```

```html
<div id="r"/>
```